# Using filterrific with API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I am attempting to use filteriffic in an application only for the real time search.
The application does not have a database serves everything by communicating with an API.
This is in my controller:

```
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
    call_api("/api/v1/site_links", {search: params[:search]}),
    params[:filterrific],
    select_options: {
    },
    persistence_id: 'mike',
    default_filter_params: {},
  ) or return
  @site_links

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
```

Right now I do not have a model related to this controller.
Whenever I try to load the page I get:

```
undefined method `filterrific_default_filter_params' for
```

I am using filterrific 2.0.5 and rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Filterrific documentation](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/), it is designed specifically for ActiveRecord models.

The call to `initialize_filterrific` requires a model class as the first parameter, which is eventually used to call `model_class.filterrific_default_filter_params`. This is why you’re getting the error.

I’ve had success creating live search with the [rails4-autocomplete gem](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete).